# How to bring values into a combo-box?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I wanted to know as to how can i filter records based in a database to place them in a combo-box. For example i have a sql statement that says: "select stock_items from stock_master where ID=XYZ" and based on this command,  I want all those values to be be shown in ComboBox1

Thanks

Comment: @David what if stock_item were an IDENTITY column?

Comment: VBA or vb.net? You've labeled both, but the answers are quite different.

Answer (score 2):

1)Using SqlCommand use your command:-(select stock_items from stock_master where ID=XYZ)
  like **SqlCommand** **com**=new SqlCommand(select stock_items from stock_master where
  ID=XYZ,connection);

2)using **SqlDataReader** Read The Data From The **Database**
  like SqlDataReader dr= **com.ExecuteReader()**;

3)using **SqlDataReader** Object Read The Particular Items..here like **Stock_items** .
   Read Data from the **SqldataReader** like this.
   E.G:-
  ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Stock_item"].toString());

THNXX..:)

Comment: sorry dude, it's showing an error that "Tables is not a part of sqldatareader"

Comment: also the brackets are all wrong!!